How does this kind of recursive equation implement analytic continuation?
If the function $f(z)$ is analytic in the right half plane, $f(1) \neq 0$, and satisfies $f(z+1)=z f(z)$, prove that $f(z)$ can be analytic continuation to the full plane, except for $z=0,-1,-2, \cdots$.
Since $f(z)$ is analytic in the region $G_0: \operatorname{Re} z>0$, then $f(z+1)$ is analytic in $G_1: \operatorname{Re} z>-1$; $f(z+2)$ is analytic in $G_2: \operatorname{Re} z>-2$; $\cdots$.
Given that $f(z+1)=z f(z)$, that is
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z} f(z+1)
$$
I'm curious about how the equation $ f(z) = \frac{1}{z} f(z+1) $ leads to their equality in a common region. I feel that it should be a condition like $ f(z) = f(z+1) $ that allows them to be the same in a common area, similar to how $ \sin x $ can coincide with itself after a translation on the real plane.
